# How to make fetch api listen to the server every 2 secs

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm making an application that on button click runs fetch api which fetches data returned from a site.That site will only send back data when the resolved var is true.So how do i  constantly keep listening when the resolved var changes and then display the response.Right now i'm just fetching data on button click.

```
const url = 'https://sarthak999.pythonanywhere.com/';
  let fetchData = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
      key: name+'$'+text
  })
}
fetch(url, fetchData)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      str = JSON.stringify(data);
      glob = "bot";
      var reply = data.split('$');
      var scrollTop = $('#mydiv').scrollTop();
      var sbHeight = window.innerHeight * (window.innerHeight / document.getElementById('mydiv').offsetHeight);
      var scroll = false;
      console.log($("#mydiv")[0].scrollHeight+" "+scrollTop+" "+sbHeight+" "+(document.getElementById('mydiv').scrollTop-
    document.getElementById('mydiv').clientHeight));
      if($("#mydiv")[0].scrollHeight!=scrollTop)
      {
        scroll=true;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < reply.length; i++) {
        $chat.append('<div class="BotWrapper">' +
            '<div class="speech-bubble z-depth-5">' +
            '<p>' + reply[i] + '</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class=""></div></div>');
            $('.typing').fadeOut();
            $("#mydiv").scrollTop($("#mydiv")[0].scrollHeight);
      }

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: use `setInterval`

Comment: @SaikatHajra but then how do i detect when i recieve a message and then close the connection

Comment: `clearInteval` is there . When you receive a message just the clear the timer. thats it

Comment: No i just want to request for thedata once and then wait for the response...and close the connection once i get that response

Comment: You can make use of socket.io